# App crashes on start when load colors from UserDefaults (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

My app is crashing when I start it on a device.

At start, all my arrays are empty.

Error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value swift

[image]

How can I fix that?

```
var CName: [String] = [""]

var BarCode: [String] = [""]
var CardNBR: [String] = [""]

var CardColorLogo = [UIColor]()

var UploadDateArray = [NSDate]()

var Comment: [String] = [""]
```

**Save and Load Function**

```
func saveColorLogo() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: CardColorLogo), forKey: "ColorsKey")
}

func loadColorLogo() {
    let decodedColorsData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ColorsKey") as? NSData
    let colorsArray = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decodedColorsData! as  Data) as! NSArray)
    CardColorLogo = colorsArray as! [UIColor]
}
```

Comment: Do not use `NSData`, use `Data`. Do not use `NSArray`, use a Swift array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter for example

```
var cardColorLogo = [UIColor]()
```

Second of all, don't use `NSData` and `NSArray` in Swift. There are native types.

**Any carelessly written exclamation mark can crash the app**.

The error occurs because `object(forKey` returns `nil` if the key does not exist. By the way, there is a `data(forKey` method with the same behavior.

Optional bind the result and return an empty array on failure

```
func loadColorLogo() {
    if let decodedColorsData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "ColorsKey"),
        let colorsArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decodedColorsData) as? [UIColor] {
        cardColorLogo = colorsArray
    } else {
        cardColorLogo = []
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but App crush on this line: cell.BackView.backgroundColor = CardColorLogo[indexPath.row], with error  Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: The array must contain the same number of items as the data source array. You are strongly discouraged anyway from using multiple arrays as data source. Use a custom class or struct.